# zindex on fixed positioned elements on IE Mobile

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index, ie-mobile

I've an issue with setting css z-index property with IEMobile 9 and IEMobile 10.

```
background-color: #333333;
display: block;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.6;
z-index: 9000;
```

Problem: Elements coming under the overlay is clickable; Button onclick is firing, can enter text to the input, text area elements etc.

This happens only in mobile version of Inter net Explorer on Windows Phone 7 and 8.

Is this a known bug? any documentation link?

live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mithun/ssV4T/1/)

Comment: Does the overlay fill the entire space of the viewport?

Comment: yes, it covers full screen, also i tried to set the height dynamically  `height: 535px`; any way the entire screen has the background color given to overlay. if i set the opacity to 1, the screen fill the background color, but still the element behind the background are clickable.

Comment: *Well,* I'm not sure if it helps but there **[was](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html)** [a bug](http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) with `z-index` on IE7.

Comment: We need some HTML code as well.

Comment: @HerrSerker http://jsfiddle.net/mithun/ssV4T/1/